# Order by Last Message

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a chat app on my website. The chat messages stored in a table with timestamp.
Also I list out all users (for now it's ordered by Username).

```
SELECT username
FROM accounts 
WHERE NOT id = 57 AND activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY username ASC;
```

I want to order the users by the last sent messages timestamp.
I managed to create the query to show only the last sent message's date for the logged in user (for now his id is 57).

```
SELECT msg_date FROM messages
WHERE outgoing_msg_id = 57
ORDER BY msg_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

How can i combine the two?

Comment: On a side note: `outgoing_msg_id` is a misleading name, as it seems to be a user account ID. and not a message ID A better name would be `outgoing_account_id` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT accounts.username
FROM accounts 
JOIN messages ON messages.incoming_msg_id = accounts.id
WHERE accounts.activation_code = 'activated'
  AND messages.outgoing_msg_id = 57
GROUP BY accounts.username
ORDER BY MAX(messages.msg_date) DESC;
```

I hope that there are no messages to self..

If you need in ALL users (even there is no messages from them) then try

```sql
SELECT accounts.username
FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.incoming_msg_id = accounts.id
                  AND messages.outgoing_msg_id = 57
WHERE accounts.activation_code = 'activated'
GROUP BY accounts.username
ORDER BY MAX(messages.msg_date) DESC;
```

Comment: works perfectly! is there a way to list out the other users as well under the results?

Comment: @Blank_ Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER one..

Comment: same result for LEFT :/

Comment: @Blank_ For LEFT JOIN you must move all conditions for right table (`AND messages.outgoing_msg_id = 57`) from WHERE to ON clause.. have you did this?

Comment: man... i completly lost. can you modify your answear, please?

Comment: @Blank_ Updated, test... the best way provide some sample data (see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) paragraph 5).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a lateral join:

```
SELECT a.username
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT MAX(msg.msg_date) AS max_msg_date
  FROM messages msg
  WHERE msg.outgoing_msg_id = a.id
) m ON true
WHERE NOT a.id = 57
AND a.activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY m.max_msg_date DESC, a.username;
```

Another is using a common join with an aggregation per user:

```
SELECT a.username
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT outgoing_msg_id, MAX(msg_date) AS max_msg_date
  FROM messages
  GROUP BY outgoing_msg_id
) m ON m.outgoing_msg_id = a.id
WHERE NOT a.id = 57
AND a.activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY m.max_msg_date DESC, a.username;
```

Yet another way is a subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT a.username
FROM accounts a
WHERE NOT a.id = 57
AND a.activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY
(
  SELECT MAX(msg.msg_date)
  FROM messages msg
  WHERE msg.outgoing_msg_id = a.id
), a.username;
```

If you want to show message data along with the user account data, the lateral join is the best approach:

```
SELECT a.*, m.*
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT *
  FROM messages msg
  WHERE msg.outgoing_msg_id = a.id
  ORDER BY msg.msg_date DESC
  LIMIT 1
) m ON true
WHERE NOT a.id = 57
AND a.activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY m.max_msg_date DESC, a.username;
```

Or use a window function to pick the latest message per user:

```
SELECT a.username
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    msg.*,
    MAX(msg_date) OVER (PARTITION BY AS outgoing_msg_id) AS max_msg_date
  FROM messages msg
  GROUP BY outgoing_msg_id
) m ON m.outgoing_msg_id = a.id AND m.msg_date = max_msg_date
WHERE NOT a.id = 57
AND a.activation_code = 'activated'
ORDER BY m.max_msg_date DESC, a.username;
```